# How can I wait for a specific code to run while when form is closed and is set to vbModeless?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro that generates a report to show that our bank and accounting records tie out for the day. In the end of the macro a `UserForm` displays only if a discrepancy is detected and allows the user to remove it from the `ListBox` once they have taken care of the discrepancy.

In order for the user to analyze the input data (which is imported into the workbook on a separate sheet) while keeping the `UserForm` open (to track the discrepancies), I simply set the `UserForm.Show vbModeless`. My issue is now that I'm trying to implement a new function to run after the `UserForm` is **closed** but with it in a `Modeless` state, it simply checks if the condition is met and moves on.

I tried to implement a `GoTo X` in the `OKButton` event listener, but I'm not sure how to have the code `GoTo` a line in the main `Module` when referenced from within the `UserForm`.

My Question: How can I keep this `UserForm` set as `Modeless`, and allow the user to navigate through the data with it open, but not continue code unless it's closed / unloaded / OkButton is pressed?

Here's the button Listener:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    '.... Code here
    Me.Hide
    LeftoverValues.Closed = true '(other UserForm if discrepancies not taken care of)
    Closed = true 'boolean to flag this as closed
    GoTo UnmatchedSummaryClosed: '(name of form, GoTo Line in module)
End Sub
```

Here's the code for the end of the macro - from calling `UserForm` to end:

```
    '... Approx 2000 lines worth of code leading to this

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Beep 'To alert users that it's 'finished'

    If WireValues.Count > 0 Or BWGPValues.Count > 0 Then
        Call DifferenceForm    'Discrepancy UserForm - Named UnmatchedSummary
    End If

    Beep   'alert to show discrepancy check is done - shows if needed

    Call warnForm

UnmatchedClosed:   'INTENDED GoTo LINE FROM USERFORM
    If UnmatchedSummary.Closed And LeftoverValues.Closed And WarningForm.Closed Then
        Call ARSummary
    End If

    Call StopTimer(time1, Started1)  'Timer to show how long macro took
    Debug.Print "Total Time: " & ShowTime(time1) & "ms"

    If UnmatchedSummary.Closed And WarningForm.Closed And ARSummaryDone Then
        End             'Also want this to happen only if everything's done
    End If              ' Don't want data to hang if user doesn't close macro template
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't use the [macros] tag for Excel/VBA questions. The tag info for it says, `*Not for MS-OFFICE / VBA / macro languages. Use the respective tags instead.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting a call to the function you want to run in the `UserForm_Terminate()` which fires when the userform is closed.

Comment: Does the `Terminate` event fire when `Me.Hide` is called?

Comment: No, only when closed or unloaded