# How to get class event working on userform in modeless?

Tags: vba, forms, class, events, modeless

The event assigned to dynamically created buttons working fine when  showmodal=True.
But what I need to do is working with the application while the userform is open.
Any help will be much appreciated. Below are the sub in module and class module
THank you.

```
Sub tests()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyB As MSForms.Control
    Dim btnEvent As MyCustomButton
    Dim colButtons As Collection
    Set colButtons = New Collection
    
    For i = 1 To 7
      
            Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            
            With MyB
                .Name = "dugme" & i
                .Caption = "Captiones" & i
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 25 * i
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = "tagi" & i
            End With
            
            Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
            Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
            Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
           colButtons.Add btnEvent
            
    
    Next i

UserForm1.Show

End Sub

--- class module MyCustomButton-------

Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton
Public frm As UserForm


Private Sub btn_Click()

    MsgBox btn.Name

End Sub
```

I tried to understand and implement the solution suggested here: [Functionalize Event Driven Modeless UserForm Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113380/functionalize-event-driven-modeless-userform-class)
But it did not work for me. My case should be much simpler and Any help will bemuch appreciated.

Comment: If I got you right then the only thing you need to do is to declare `Dim colButtons As Collection` on a module level. In this way it will survive the end of your test sub.

Comment: Sub Tests is sitting in a module and I added Dim colButtons As Collection, thank you. However, the issue has not gone away. I am viewing the userform, btn_Click() works in showmodal = true but not in modless version, which is I am looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my comment was not clear enough. Of course one also has to remove or replace  `Set colButtons = New Collection` otherwise one will always create a new instance (is that the correct english word for this?) of the collection.

My complete suggestion would be to change the posted code as follows

```
Option Explicit
' the New keyword will take care that a new instance is created if needed
Dim colButtons As New Collection

Sub tests()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyB As MSForms.Control
    Dim btnEvent As MyCustomButton
'    Dim colButtons As Collection
'    Set colButtons = New Collection
    
    For i = 1 To 7
      
            Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            
            With MyB
                .Name = "dugme" & i
                .Caption = "Captiones" & i
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 25 * i
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = "tagi" & i
            End With
            
            Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
            Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
            Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
           colButtons.Add btnEvent
            
    
    Next i

UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Another approach would be to check if there is already an active instance like that

```
Option Explicit
Dim colButtons As Collection

Sub tests()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyB As MSForms.Control
    Dim btnEvent As MyCustomButton
'    Dim colButtons As Collection
'    Set colButtons = New Collection
   If colButtons Is Nothing Then
    Set colButtons = New Collection
   End If
    
    For i = 1 To 7
      
            Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            
            With MyB
                .Name = "dugme" & i
                .Caption = "Captiones" & i
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 25 * i
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = "tagi" & i
            End With
            
            Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
            Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
            Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
           colButtons.Add btnEvent
            
    
    Next i

UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

I'd also recommend to do some reading on [scope of variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) and [objects](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-objects/)